# Javascript (learning)

Tags: javascript, validation

I am learning about javascript from the book "JavaScript Bible", but I have some difficulties.
I'm trying to understand this code:

```
function checkIt(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        status = "This field accept only numbers."
        return false
    }
    status = ""
    return true
}
```

Someone can explain to me?

Comment: Your question is too vague. What specifically do you want an explanation about?

Comment: I can't believe somebody would publish a book that promoted writing JavaScript code without semi-colons.  I hope this is from the chapter entitled _Horrible example code that should never be imitated_.

Comment: To answer your question, it looks like it's code that is intended to validate input to ensure that only numbers are entered.  Keep reading your book for more information ;)

Comment: lol @jahroy, but I have to agree relying on ASI is not a natural thing for most developers and worse of all, makes it look like CoffeeScript (even though "compiled" CS does add semi-colons to the JS).

Comment: I think the obvious difficulty is in evt = (evt)? ... structure, which basically is because javascript functions can be called with any number of parameters. That sentence checks if evt was assigned a value  by caller; if not, it takes "window.event" as the parameter. The second similar thing is because the objects in javascript are very dynamic. Window.event can have 'keyCode' or 'which' or whatever methods. Thus it takes 'which' the primary attribute to get the value from -- if it's present and if which doesn't evaluate to false.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could tell us from where the function is being triggered, is it from an `input`'s `onkeydown`/`onkeypress` attribute? Even though that's quite obvious for some, it'd help making a more accurate explanation.

Comment: Aside from the semicolonless code which I don't mind that much, I get nervous when I see `evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event` or `(evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode`. The most common practice is to use the `||` operator `evt = evt || event`. Maybe it's mentioned later on in the book?

Comment: @elclanrs You know both will be interpreted to the same and return a syntax error in case the variable/object you're testing hasn't been defined anywhere. I'd even prefer `if (!evt) evt = window.event;` for readability, or `evt || (evt=window.event);` for performance, but the usual `evt = evt || event;` is a more standard way of doing things yeah.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: I've never had problems of that sort, if you mean I should put `window.event`, yes you're probably right, but I don't see the need for the other options you propose, the first one is basically the same as using the `||` operator, and the second one seems a bit weird, valid, but weird.

Comment: @elclanrs That's what I said, all 4 options (OP, your defaulting operator and my 2 other options) all return the same result. `=]`

Comment: Yup, it's all about preference really. When I see `a || ...` my mind thinks about `if (!a) { //run function }` not about an assignment, but that's just me...

Comment: Same. `=]` ps. My second method apparently doesn't validate on JSHint and I first saw it when using Google Closure Compiler, after some testing on jsperf it seems to be about 10x faster than the default defaulting operation (`foo = foo || bar;`), but that's just in the micro/milliseconds so probably not worth it. `:P`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I assume that you just want us to explain what the code does. If so, see below:

```
// Create a function named checkIt, which takes an argument evt.
function checkIt(evt) {

    // If the user has passed something in the argument evt, take it.
    // Else, take the window.event as evt.
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;

    // Get the Character Code. It can be either from evt.which or evt.keyCode,
    // depending on the browser.
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

    // If the Character is not a number, the do not allow the user to type in.
    // The reason for giving 31 to 48 and greater than 57 is because, each key
    // you type has its own unique character code. From 31 to 48, are the numeric
    // keys in the keyboard.
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {

        // Give a status informing the user.
        status = "This field accept only numbers.";

        // Prevent the default action of entering the character.
        return false;
    }

    // Clear the status
    status = "";

    // Allow the user to enter text.
    return true;
}
```

#### ASCII Code Reference

[image]
<sub>(source: [cdrummond.qc.ca](http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/professeurs/alain/images/ASCII1.GIF))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [cdrummond.qc.ca](http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/professeurs/alain/Images/ascii2.gif))</sub>

***PS:*** I edited your code adding semi-colons `;` which were missing.

Comment: Should add that the 31, 48, and 57 are decimal values for characters. See [Ascii table](http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/professeurs/alain/files/ascii.htm). It also would have made more sense to check if the code **is** a number than checking a limited number of ascii codes to see if it is not.

Comment: @ jahroy in the book, this example appeared without the ";". If this is a bad book, could you please point me to good books. I have doubt to understand the whole function. I am beginner in javascript and I am not familiar with window.event or even use "?" / ":". This book has a very superficial approach to the subject and I'm with dificulties to undestand.

Comment: @user1746040 You can consider checking out this book: [JavaScript for Dummies, 2nd Edition](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Dummies-Edition-Emily-Vander/dp/0764502239) by Emily A. Vander Veer, Rich Tennant.

Answer (score 0):

it basically says:

```
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event
```

If "evt" is a value, then carry on otherwise assign window.event to evt. This is a shorthand if statement

```
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
```

Make a new variable and if a child of evt ("which") exists then assign it to the newly made variable, if not assign "evt" child; "KeyCode"

```
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
            status = "This field accept only numbers."
            return false
}
```

if charcode is greater than 31 and charcode is smaller than 48 or bigger than 57, then procede. Assign a string to the var status and returns false which terminates the function ( meaning something went wrong)

```
status = ""
return true
```

if all went well in the above statement then assign any empty string to "status" and return true which means everything went well

Comment: `otherwise stop`? no, that's not what it says.